# Div fades out before toggle() is called

Tags: jquery, css, toggle

I'm trying to create a custom toggle. Here is the code that predefines the toggle:

```
$('.information').toggle(function() {
    $('.work-overlay').fadeOut();
    $('.information-overlay').fadeIn();
    $('body').css({'overflow':'visible'});
    e.preventDefault();
}, function() {
    $('.work-overlay').fadeOut();
    $('.information-overlay').fadeOut();
    $('body').css({'overflow':'hidden'});
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

And here is the code being called:

```
$(".information").click(function() {
    $(".information").toggle();
})
```

However, before anything is clicked, the `.information` div fades out.

Would anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't work to use `toggle` that way in jQuery 1.9+. They removed the function.

> ```
> .toggle(function, function, ... ) removed
> ```

[**Documentation**](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed)

**Alt**

```
var infoClicked =false;
$(".information").click(function () {
    if (infoClicked == false) {
        $('.work-overlay').fadeOut();
        $('.information-overlay').fadeIn();
        $('body').css({
            'overflow': 'visible'
        });
        infoClicked = true;
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        infoClicked = false;
        $('.work-overlay').fadeOut();
        $('.information-overlay').fadeOut();
        $('body').css({
            'overflow': 'hidden'
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    }
})
```

Or try this

```
var visible = 'hidden'
$(".information").click(function (e) {
      $('.work-overlay').fadeToggle();
      $('.information-overlay').fadeToggle();
      $('body').css({
          'overflow': visible
      });
      visible == 'visible' ? visible = 'hidden' : visible = 'visible';
      e.preventDefault();
  });
```